# Where is the "add Folder" icon?

Tags: filemanager

i just wondered where the add folder icon has gone? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I'm not aware if it was there in the past, because normally i don't use the filemanager at all :)

Is this normal or is something weird on my system?

[image: Where is the add folder icon?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Add Folder" button went away a little while ago, but there are three ways to create folders from the UI:

1. Right click in an open space:
   [image: Right Click]
2. Click the "List" (three horizontal lines) icon in the upper corner, then click on the folder with a [+]:
   [image: Folder Plus]
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Choose whichever one works best for your workflow.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: You can add [this one too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tZeg.png).

Comment: Ok thanks - thats it ;)